# awk to print a column data when pattern matches on a particular column

Tags: awk

I have input file

```
ABC 123      DEF  456
ZYX 098      WVU  765
PQR 111      RST  333
```

Now I am trying to display 3rd and 4th Column if pattern matches in column 1, and display 1st and 2nd column if patter matches on 3rd column.

```
awk '{{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i == "ABC") printf $(i+2)" "$(i+3)" "} print ""; }'
```

This does the job but input will be a variable as in so I don't know if it will match on column 1 or column 3.

```
x=ABC or x=DEF 
awk -v x="$x" '{{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==x) printf $(i+2)" "$(i+3)" "} print ""; }'
```

(Depending upon the input value of x, so if I can compare Field no as well it should do the job)

Expected Output
if x=ABC

```
DEF  456
```

if x=DEF

```
ABC 123
```

And so on for each line....

Comment: What's the expected output here ?

Comment: KISS: `'$1 == x || $2 == x {print $3, $4} $3 == x {print $1, $2}'`

Comment: @don_crissti Updated my question.

Comment: as suggested `awk -vx="$x" '$1 == x {print $3, $4} $3 == x {print $1, $2}'`

Comment: @don_crissti It did the job, thanks. Any other option you can think of? Post an answer so I can select it as answer

Comment: @don_crissti Done.

Comment: @don_crissti I am facing an interesting situation here, it doesn't work on a particular system, this code it works perfectly in all but this machine, could you think of any reason why?

Comment: I don't know... make sure your files are unix files not dos CRLFs; other than that and without seeing the input I have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -vx="$x" '$1 == x {print $3, $4} $3 == x {print $1, $2}'
```

@don_crissti This seems to do the job just fine.